# Using appendChild multiple times with the same node in JS

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm writing a form validation script for a form with multiple ratings, and I'd like to insert a bit of text that says "give a rating!" for each rating the user misses. I wrote the code below to do this, but I'm running into a problem where the give_rating node is only appended to the last node on the form. I know that this is because appendChild basically moves a node instead of duplicating it, and I tried solving this using cloneNode but that just breaks my JS entirely.

Anyway, here's the code. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help,

Chris

```
var give_rating = document.createElement('span');
give_rating.className='small red';
give_rating.innerHTML = '<strong> &nbsp;Give a rating!</strong>';

document.getElementById('rating1').appendChild(give_rating);
document.getElementById('rating2').appendChild(give_rating);
```

When I use the code above code give_rating is only appended to 'rating2'.

```
document.getElementById('rating1').appendChild(give_rating.cloneNode(True));
document.getElementById('rating2').appendChild(give_rating.cloneNode(True));
```

When I use this code the entire script fails. How do I add an instance of "Give a rating!" for each rating on my form that the user fails to fill out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive: `True` should be `true` (lower case).

Comment: OMG casablanca, I literally downloaded Firebug right after submitting this question, ran Console and figured this out. Thanks for your response. JS drives me nuts :)

Answer (score 9):

1. You can only insert the created html elements or document pieces once.  So, you have to call the cloneNode() function.
2. The javascript is case-sensitive. So, it should be `cloneNode(true)`, instead of `cloneNode(True)`.
3. You can turn on the javascript debugger of the browser (both Chrome and IE/Edge) by pressing `F12`.  Then you can see what happen to your script.